# Как дописать чтобы марка выводилась в обоих таблицах?

Tags: php, mysql

При выполнении условия vip = 1 марки выводяться в выпадающем списке 1;
При выполнении условия vip = 2 марки выводяться в выпадающем списке 2; 
При выполнении условия vip = 0 марка вообще нигде не выводится

```
if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля')  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND vip = 2 ORDER BY name ASC";
            else $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1  AND vip = 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
```

**Вопрос:** Как дописать чтобы марка выводилась в обоих Таблицах?

```
    таблица: t_model
id    alias        parent_id    name         logo         descr status  vip
8000 a6-allr-13     283     А6 allroad       Allroad13.jpg  NULL    1   0

if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля') ($vip = 2)  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND vip = 2 ORDER BY name ASC";
        else if($vip = 1) $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1  AND vip = 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
        else ($vip = 3) $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1  AND vip = 3 ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Вопрос закрыт.

**Правильно ответил jMind:** для первого sql AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3); для второго AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3. Спасибо ему!

Comment: как у вас хранится марка?
что такое таблица 1 и таблица 2?
зачем вы полностью копируете sql-запрос? если у вас отличие только в условии "vip =" ?

Comment: Во этот caveat я люблю примерно так же, как точку с запятой после конструкции с if:

    if($vip = 1)

Здесь переменной будет присвоена единица, а само выражение успешно скастуется в `true`, поэтому что там дальше в else написано - без разницы.

А вот это будет всегда выводить ошибку:

    if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля')
        ($vip = 2)
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND vip = 2 ORDER BY name ASC";
    else

Потому что if без фигурных скобок относится только к единственной следующей конструкции, поэтому у else нет if-родителя

Comment: Может вам это надо?

if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля') 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND vip = " . $vip . " ORDER BY name ASC";

Comment: По столбцу VIP у меня идет или 2-ки или 1-цы. Если по столбцу VIP - 0, то модель не выводиться ни там ни там. На сегодня задача стоит чтобы отдельные модели с vip=3 были и в 1-ом меню и во 2-ом меню(изначально так и было $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 ORDER BY name ASC"; везде список моделей одинаковый(и в первом и во втором меню). Необходимость стала разделить эти списки - поэтому была введена колонка vip, с помощью которой мы разделили весь список моделей на 2 части. А теперь необходимо чтобы не все, а только отдельные модели попадали в 1-й и во 2-й список

Comment: для первого sql AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3);
для второго AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3)

Comment: jMind прошу еще помощи!!!

{
$DBbrand_opt[0] = _PLEASE_SELECT;
  
if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля')  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";

else $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1  AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";
}

Comment: Получается так, что у нас при этом коде есть:


-список только с вип Моделями (vip=3);

- список Общий (список моделей + вип модели)(vip=2);

Но при редактировании Автомобиля нужно чтобы появлялся "список Общий (список моделей + вип модели)", а у меня появляеться  "список только с вип Моделями".

Как решить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция if else подразумевает выбор из 2 возможных вариантов. В вашем случае vip = 2  или vip = 1.
Если вам нужен третий вариант, то надо переделать в

```
if(условие 1) 
    sql = "sql 1";
else if(условие 2)
    sql = "sql 2";
else
    sql = "sql 3";
```

Comment: Опишите словами задачу.
И что такое vip?

Comment: Vip Колонка в таблице БД таблица: t_model (см. вверху). Соответственно идет сравнение. Если стоит 1 то модель выводиться в выпадающем меню 1- формы. 
Если стоит 2 то модель выводиться в выпадающем меню 2- формы.  Работающий вариант:
$DBbrand_opt[0] = _PLEASE_SELECT;
if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля')  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND vip = 2 ORDER BY name ASC";
else $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1  AND vip = 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
Задача стала чтобы модель была и там и там.

Comment: У вас и там и там SELECT * FROM t_models и отличие лишь в vip = 2 и  vip = 1.
Если у вас в первом случае выводятся модели, а во втором нет, то значит для второго варианта нет нужных записей в базе.